# Is there any intelligence in heart?

Tags: brain, cardiology, nervous-system, iq-intelligence

Is it correct to say that heart and brain both are center of intellect ?  Has there been any scientific study done to prove that like Brain, Heart also has intelligence and there are heart-signals just like we have brain-signals ?  What is the current state of our understanding in this regard?

I am not a biology student so finding it difficult to find a relevant reference.

Thank you very much for your answers and comments.

**Edit** 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6fVwufEZi2Y

Comment: Except from metaphysics, which are no medical topic, where did you hear about this?

Comment: @BUMMI https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6fVwufEZi2Y

Comment: Ahh Gregg Braden - he's crank and woo-meister who makes his living by selling new age word salad in books and seminar form.

Comment: @motosubatsu - woo-meister. heh, great turn of phrase.

Comment: @JohnP hehe.. thanks, shamelessly stolen of course!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a basic biology/physiology topic.

Comment: @DoctorWhom The heart is the only organ with its own action potential system (apart from the brain), so These two do stand out. I guess the main difference is that the conduction system of the heart is a specialised type of muscle cells, and that they only carry visceromotoric „nerves“. Talking about consciousness seems more of a philosophical question, and of course no, the heart doesn’t have any intellect. But I think one can dive deeper into functional anatomy and physiology than motsubatsu‘s good but basic answer, and I wouldn’t close this question as too-basic. Saying it’s too much

Comment: biology: Well, medicine is just a combination of all sciences, so I guess almost everything can be migrated to another site. I would prefer to have Anatomy questions here and not over at biology though....

Comment: @Narusan The question was put on hold based on not being about medical science (as defined here), not because it was about anatomy. I agree with that reasoning because the question fails the test of being within the realm of accepted science.

Answer (score 3):

The [heart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heart) is not a center of intellect, it's a multi-chambered pump made primarily out of muscle.

There *are* however "heart signals", at least in a sense. The [Sinoatrial Node](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinoatrial_node) is a specialized group of cells in the heart that produces regular action potentials across the cell membranes in the heart (causing the contractions that pump the blood) but this isn't an intellect or anything like that, just a regular cycle that provides the heart's sinus rhythm (essentially the "default" heart rate), the bodies autonomic nervous system (via the release of different chemicals) can influence the rate of these action potentials to raise or lower heart rate.

Comment: hmm, not a biology student, but isn't that any organ in the body can have signals? The electric signals are from the difference between inside and outside cell membrane, and thus collectively any organ should have a signal for itself?

Comment: @Ooker Just because a cell happens to have a difference in charge across the cell membrane doesn't mean that charge has functionality. The only tissues in the body that use electrical charges for their functionality are muscle and nerve tissue. Most signaling in the body is chemical, not electrical.

Comment: I see. But let's take the electrical signal of the liver for example. Can it show how the liver is healthy or not? Chemical reactions are basically exchanging electrons, which is also a weak electrical signal. (I'm not really sure about this)